# github actions keeps on timing out (or something) well under my timeout limit

Tags: github-actions

First, here's my .github/workflows/ci.yml file:

```
name: Benchmark

on:
  push

jobs:
  benchmark:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        PHP_VERSION: [
          '4.4',
          '5.0', '5.1', '5.2', '5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6',
          '7.1', '7.2', '7.3', '7.4',
          '8.0', '8.0jit', '8.1', '8.1jit', '8.2', '8.2jit'
        ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: "Setup Docker and Git Repo"
        run: |
          git clone -b 1.0 --single-branch https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib.git
          if [[ "${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}" == "8"* ]]; then docker pull "quay.io/phpseclib/php${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}" && docker image tag "quay.io/phpseclib/php${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}" "phpseclib/php${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}"; else docker pull "phpseclib/php${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}"; fi
      - name: "Run Benchmark"
        run: |
          docker run -v "`pwd`:/opt/src" \
            -w "/opt/src" \
            "phpseclib/php${{ matrix.PHP_VERSION }}" \
            php test.php
    timeout-minutes: 10
```

On Github Action pretty much every job looks like this:

```
Cloning into 'phpseclib'...
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from phpseclib/php4.4
2b15b7abe8b3: Pulling fs layer
292ae618967d: Pulling fs layer
71bbdbc9d3c1: Pulling fs layer
963fe8c066a2: Pulling fs layer
963fe8c066a2: Waiting
71bbdbc9d3c1: Verifying Checksum
71bbdbc9d3c1: Download complete
2b15b7abe8b3: Verifying Checksum
2b15b7abe8b3: Download complete
963fe8c066a2: Verifying Checksum
963fe8c066a2: Download complete
2b15b7abe8b3: Pull complete
292ae618967d: Verifying Checksum
292ae618967d: Download complete
292ae618967d: Pull complete
71bbdbc9d3c1: Pull complete
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

At that top it says `cancelled 5 minutes ago in 21s`. It's like it's just timing out after 21s even tho I have `timeout-minutes: 10` set.

I thought I'd try it without the matrix but without it works just fine:

```
name: Benchmark

on:
  push

jobs:
  benchmark:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: "Setup Docker and Git Repo"
        run: |
          git clone -b 1.0 --single-branch https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib.git
          docker pull "phpseclib/php7.4"
      - name: "Run Benchmark"
        run: |
          docker run -v "`pwd`:/opt/src" -w "/opt/src" "phpseclib/php7.4" php test.php
    timeout-minutes: 10
```

Like without the matrix the docker container is able to be pulled and ran, all within the 10m `timeout-minutes`.

TLDR I can't figure this out my first Github Actions YAML is timing out when my second one doesn't have any issues what-so-ever.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other job in the matrix failing for an obvious and clear reason? Are they still all cancelled if you add `fail-fast: false`? See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#handling-failures

Comment: @Zeitounator - `fail-fast: false` gives me a "_The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/ci.yml (Line: 8, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'fail-fast'_" error. https://pastebin.com/nrb7FjXG shows where I put it. That said, I did have another failing job. When I removed that other failing job all the others ran - nice catch! Would `fail-fast: false` change that behavior?

Comment: Fail fast is not positionned correctly in your yaml on pastebin. Please review the documentation linked above.

Comment: @Zeitounator - now I'm getting "_The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/ci.yml (Line: 10, Col: 20): Unexpected value 'false'_". My updated YAML: https://pastebin.com/ycGE7pvx

Comment: ... which is the exact same error as above because the parameter is still not at the right place i.e at the same level as `matrix:` right under `strategy:`, as you can see in the example in the above documentation. Please do not paste an other similar error without double checking and debugging on your side as expected from all users here. Thanks.

Comment: ^ See [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.fail-fast`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategyfail-fast). You may use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your workflow and fix it.